# How do I use CSP value on ASP.NET MVC Layout with Helper Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html-helper, content-security-policy

With ASP.NET Core, I provide strict content security policy. But I need to set the nonce key value that I use on the middleware from the value on the layout. **I want to write a Helper method, but how can I get the "nonceContainer" id value on the Layout into the method.** How can i this?

```
    public static HtmlString NonceKey(this IHtmlHelper helper)
    {

        string nonceValue = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["nonce-key"].ToString();
        return new HtmlString(nonceValue);
    }
```

[I want to this value within Helper Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQRzA.png)

Comment: Hi @DevGuBa, Where do you set the value of the HttpContext?

Comment: I'm setting it up with middleware in startup. Then I set the layout in the input

Comment: I try the code you provided, It can works well. I don't undserstand `what's but how can I get the "nonceContainer" id value on the Layout`?